# Ruby on Rails - Converting Twitter @mentions, #hashtags and URLs within a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Let's say I have a string which contains text grabbed from Twitter, as follows:

```
myString = "I like using @twitter, because I learn so many new things! [line break]
Read my blog: http://www.myblog.com #procrastination"
```

The tweet is then presented in a view. However, prior to this, I'd like to convert the string so that, in my view:

1. @twitter links to http://www.twitter.com/twitter
2. The URL is turned into a link (in which the URL remains the link text)
3. #procrastination is turned into https://twitter.com/i/#!/search/?q=%23procrastination, in which #procrastination is the link text

I'm sure there must be a gem out there that would allow me to do this, but I can't find one. I have come across [twitter-text-rb](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb) but I can't quite work out how to apply it to the above. I've done it in PHP using regex and a few other methods, but it got a bit messy!

Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [twitter-text](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-text) gem has pretty much all the work covered for you. Install it manually (`gem install twitter-text`, use sudo if needed) or add it to your Gemfile (`gem 'twitter-text'`) if you are using bundler and do `bundle install`.

Then include the Twitter auto-link library (`require 'twitter-text'` and `include Twitter::Autolink`) at the top of your class and call the method `auto_link(inputString)` with the input string as the parameter and it will give you the auto linked version

Full code:

```
require 'twitter-text'
include Twitter::Autolink

myString = "I like using @twitter, because I learn so many new things! [line break] 
Read my blog: http://www.myblog.com #procrastination"

linkedString = auto_link(myString)
```

If you output the contents of linkedString, you get the following output:

```
I like using @<a class="tweet-url username" href="https://twitter.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">twitter</a>, because I learn so many new things! [line break] 
Read my blog: <a href="http://www.myblog.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.myblog.com</a> <a class="tweet-url hashtag" href="https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23procrastination" rel="nofollow" title="#procrastination">#procrastination</a>
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks. So, in my view, I take it I need to use something like 'auto_link' to make sure the links display correctly?

Comment: To clarify my above query, my view displays the string as plain text, that is links are not HTML links. So, the text is being correctly converted, but isn't being displayed as expected in my view.

Comment: Well the tool adds the relevant markup to turn the links into actual HTML links for hashtags, usernames and links within a tweet. Would you be able to post a screenshot of how it shows and how it should show?

Comment: Got it - I had to add .html_safe to the end of the string, i.e to display the above in my view, the code is something like `<p><%= linkedString.html_safe %>`

Comment: Yep that would be necessary if you are using Rails. I assumed this was general Ruby itself but glad you got it sorted

Comment: @Graeme Make sure that you are not calling `.html_safe` on a string that originally came from a user input.

Read 1:
[makandracards - everything you know about html_safe is wrong](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong)

Read 2:
[you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Tweet Linkify](https://github.com/terenceponce/jquery.tweet-linkify)

A small jQuery plugin that transforms @mention texts into hyperlinks pointing to the actual Twitter profile, #hashtag texts into real hashtag searches, as well as hyperlink texts into actual hyperlinks