# Rails 4: how to identify and format links, hashtags and mentions in model attributes?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, hashtag

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Post` model, with `:copy` and `:short_copy` as custom attributes (strings).

These attributes contain copies for social medias (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Pinterest, etc.).

I display the content of these attributes in my `Posts#Show` view.

Currently, URLs, #hashtags and @mentions are formatted like the rest of the text.

What I would like to do is to format them in a different fashion, for instance in another color or in bold.

I found the [twitter-text gem](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb), which seems to offer such features, but my problem is that I do NOT need — and do NOT want — to have these URLs, #hashtags and @mentions turn into real links.

Indeed, it looks like the twitter-text gem converts URLs, #hashtags and @mentions by default with `Twitter::Autolink`, as explained in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547496/ruby-on-rails-converting-twitter-mentions-hashtags-and-urls-within-a-string).

That's is not what I am looking for: I just want to update the style of my URLs, #hashtags and @mentions.

How can I do this in Ruby / Rails?

—————

**UPDATE**:

Following Wes Foster's answer, I implemented the following method in `post.rb`:

```
def highlight(string)
  string.gsub!(/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
end
```

Then, I defined the following CSS class:

```
.highlight {
    color: #337ab7;
}
```

Last, I implemented `<%= highlight(post.copy) %>` in the desired view.

I now get the following error:

```
ArgumentError
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
<td><%= highlight(post.copy) %></td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

—————

Comment: Use a regex and wrap them in `<span class="hashtag">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure each of the following regex patterns could be improved to match even more options, however, the following code works for me:

```
def highlight_url(str)
    str.gsub!(/(https?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '[\1]')
end

def highlight_hashtag(str)
    str.gsub!(/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/, '[#\1]')
end

def highlight_mention(str)
    str.gsub!(/\B(\@[a-z0-9_-]+)/i, '[\1]')
end

# Initial string
str = "Myself and @doggirl bought a new car: http://carpictures.com #nomoremoney"

# Pass through each
highlight_mention(str)
highlight_hashtag(str)
highlight_url(str)

puts str   # > Myself and [@doggirl] bought a new car: [http://carpictures.com] [#nomoremoney]
```

In this example, I've wrapped the matches with brackets `[]`. You should use a `span` tag and style it. Also, you can wrap all three `gsub!` into a single method for simplicity.

**Updated for the asker's add-on error question**

It looks like the error is references another method named `highlight`. Try changing the name of the method from highlight to `new_highlight` to see if that fixes the new problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I am trying to use a span as you recommend, but this causes some syntax error. This is what I tried doing, for instance in the first method: `def highlight(string)
    string..gsub!(/(https?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
  end` Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: @ThibaudClement You have 2 dots in your code: `string..gsub`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I believe the problem comes from the `'`and the `"` that I use. Don't you think?

Comment: What is the exact error? I don't think it would be the quotes. Maybe update the end of your question so I can see your exact code and the error

Comment: You were right, there was no issue related to quotes. However, I now get a new error, as you can see in my **UPDATE**.

Comment: I have updated the method to `new_highlight`, both in the model and in the view, and I get `NoMethodError undefined method `new_highlight'`.

Comment: Add your `new_highlight` in a view helper, not in your model. Or if you are going to implement it into your model, you'll need to reference it from the instance of that model. For example: `post.new_highlight`

Comment: Ok. So, I updated the method in the model to `def new_highlight
    self.copy.gsub!(/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
  end` and then updated the view with 'post.new_highlight'. This does not cause any error, but not, I have `<span class="highlight">Test</span>`, ie the `<span>` tags are displayed as text instead of being injected into the HTML.

Comment: This gets into the basics of Rails and MVC. Put the code in a view helper, use `raw` to ensure the HTML doesn't get escaped, and you'll be set.

Comment: Ok, will do. Just a quick question: this method is supposed to format the attribute of a post, but will be displayed in a calendar view. So, should I define the method in the `posts_helper` or the `calendars_helper`?

Comment: You can choose whichever makes the most sense to you. I would choose `posts_helper`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am not very experienced and I am trying to learn as I go, so this kind of guidance is really useful ;)