# Rails 4: helper method working locally, breaking on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, format, helper

I have a Rails 4 app, with a `Post` model, which contains a custom `:copy` attribute.

[As recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242512/rails-4-how-to-identify-and-format-links-hashtags-and-mentions-in-model-attrib/33242871?noredirect=1#comment54296110_33242871), I created the following methods in `posts_helper.rb` to add a specific style to links, hashtags and mentions in the content of `:copy`:

```
def link_highlight(string)
    string.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
  end

  def hashtag_highlight(string)
    string.to_s.gsub!(/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/, '<span class="highlight">#\1</span>')
  end

  def mention_highlight(string)
    string.to_s.gsub!(/\B(\@[a-z0-9_-]+)/i, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
  end

  def new_highlight(string)
    link_highlight(string)
    hashtag_highlight(string)
    mention_highlight(string)
  end
```

Then, in my Calendars#Show view, where I display the content of the `:copy` attribute, I have:

```
<%= raw new_highlight(post.copy) %>
```

—————

**UPDATE**: I have also tried to move the `raw` method from the view to the helper, but still got the same results.

—————

This works perfectly locally:

[image]

However, as soon as I deploy to Heroku, where I should have the content of the `:copy` attribute, I just have nothing.

I do not get any error message.

Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2015-10-22T22:14:32.177739+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-10-22T22:14:33.045814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100952+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100980+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.13.4 (ruby 2.0.0-p645), codename: A Midsummer Code's Dream
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100981+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100981+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100982+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2015-10-22T22:14:36.100982+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2015-10-22T22:14:37.981682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-10-22T22:14:39.407860+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:52687
2015-10-22T22:14:39.408079+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2015-10-22T22:14:39.424709+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
2015-10-22T22:14:39.434794+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 1 (pid: 11) booted, phase: 0
2015-10-22T22:14:44.770104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-10-22T22:14:46.225951+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2015-10-22T22:14:47.033061+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] === puma shutdown: 2015-10-22 22:14:47 +0000 ===
2015-10-22T22:14:47.033068+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Goodbye!
2015-10-22T22:14:48.119725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-10-22T22:15:09.137041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024358+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024410+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.13.4 (ruby 2.0.0-p645), codename: A Midsummer Code's Dream
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024430+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024454+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024479+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2015-10-22T22:15:13.024502+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2015-10-22T22:15:16.803059+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:30586
2015-10-22T22:15:16.803071+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2015-10-22T22:15:16.818204+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
2015-10-22T22:15:16.823176+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
2015-10-22T22:15:17.269140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-10-22T22:15:19.171926+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.249.88.82 at 2015-10-22 22:15:19 +0000
2015-10-22T22:15:19.325329+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
2015-10-22T22:15:19.342732+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"
2015-10-22T22:15:19.352489+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_home_header.html.erb (4.9ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:19.357628+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_cta.html.erb (0.6ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:19.305513+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2015-10-22T22:15:19.334229+00:00 app[web.1]:    (3.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "calendars"
2015-10-22T22:15:19.345627+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/homepage (34.5ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:19.355907+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.2ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:19.358397+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 31.6ms | ActiveRecord: 18.2ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:19.361256+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=258aefce-534f-4612-b3df-ba4930bca1d9 fwd="24.205.62.204,66.249.88.82" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=192ms status=499 bytes=6532
2015-10-22T22:15:20.171154+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.205.62.204 at 2015-10-22 22:15:20 +0000
2015-10-22T22:15:20.310024+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CalendarsController#index as HTML
2015-10-22T22:15:20.219029+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.491337+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "calendars".* FROM "calendars" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.727624+00:00 app[web.1]:   Comment Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "posts"."calendar_id" = "calendars"."id" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND ("comments"."user_id" != $2)  ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["user_id", 1], ["user_id", 1]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.813360+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 39]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.716275+00:00 app[web.1]:    (5.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "posts"."calendar_id" = "calendars"."id" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND ("comments"."user_id" != $2)  [["user_id", 1], ["user_id", 1]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.907612+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.901873+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.911719+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.916169+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.919457+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.924117+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.922513+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.927020+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.928461+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered calendars/index.html.erb within layouts/calendars (477.2ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:20.936844+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_app_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:20.939230+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 627ms (Views: 449.5ms | ActiveRecord: 53.5ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:20.939775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=185b8006-2a24-4c46-ab7a-a54dfd28426a fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=774ms status=200 bytes=6085
2015-10-22T22:15:20.891430+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.909413+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.905320+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 36]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.914656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.918590+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.933923+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_app_header.html.erb (3.1ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:20.920311+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.926179+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.923275+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2015-10-22T22:15:20.928028+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:21.126130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-e8cebe24aff6ef7ad69efb41d7c5711a9989222e399d255e9e837b1d885140d5.css" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=5fd9e6c0-171b-4ce6-a131-0f5373e938f6 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=304 bytes=93
2015-10-22T22:15:21.224378+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6ffeee9db4d53ff7b400a1972dc1e2b2a70f00df1f241a15e6f46ebb4a960b08.js" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=ef81fff1-287b-403a-aff1-34169f1d0650 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=93
2015-10-22T22:15:21.328775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/calendy-social-media-calendar-tool-logo-216edd59c104b197d08537c3e1725cc02f70fdb89f5218c6b84ca2677feb32a5.png" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=5cec4773-d7a8-42a4-beac-965e8ae3638a fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=93
2015-10-22T22:15:21.427726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logos/small_thumb/missing.png" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=79728d60-fdbd-4587-8adb-71d8f1146aab fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1390
2015-10-22T22:15:21.434150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=d9f5b809-806b-4ec3-a148-0413ec58b7e7 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=93
2015-10-22T22:15:21.440134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/create_new_calendar.png" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=04cd55fd-f830-4993-80c8-02fd7c21e98f fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=1315
2015-10-22T22:15:21.656933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=908c6fae-fa39-454c-a947-89a54dbfb8e5 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=3885
2015-10-22T22:15:29.556393+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/calendars/2" for 24.205.62.204 at 2015-10-22 22:15:29 +0000
2015-10-22T22:15:29.698319+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CalendarsController#show as HTML
2015-10-22T22:15:29.698341+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
2015-10-22T22:15:29.797049+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" WHERE "calendars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:30.377005+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (5.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-10-22T22:15:30.689275+00:00 app[web.1]:   Calendar Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "calendars".* FROM "calendars" INNER JOIN "administrations" ON "calendars"."id" = "administrations"."calendar_id" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "calendars"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:31.034753+00:00 app[web.1]:    (3.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = $1 AND (Extract(month from date) = 10) AND (Extract(year from date) = 2015)  [["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:31.044658+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."calendar_id" = $1 AND (Extract(month from date) = 10) AND (Extract(year from date) = 2015)  ORDER BY date ASC  [["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:31.380322+00:00 app[web.1]:   Comment Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" IN (8, 34, 35, 36, 9, 37, 38, 11)
2015-10-22T22:15:31.490695+00:00 app[web.1]:   Administration Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.022820+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.046003+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.073869+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.098074+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.137289+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered calendars/show.html.erb within layouts/calendars (1294.9ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:32.146407+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_app_footer.html.erb (1.5ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:32.035637+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.065673+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.084310+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.116082+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "administrations".* FROM "administrations" WHERE "administrations"."user_id" = $1 AND "administrations"."calendar_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["calendar_id", 2]]
2015-10-22T22:15:32.143435+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_app_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:32.147188+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2449ms (Views: 1344.0ms | ActiveRecord: 144.9ms)
2015-10-22T22:15:32.159294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/calendars/2" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=34fe86a2-9114-4f39-b90a-91b787a4df4a fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2616ms status=200 bytes=37572
2015-10-22T22:15:32.489404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-3c4a1bb7ce3234407184f0d80cc4dec075e4ad616b44dcc5778e1cfb1bc24019.woff2" host=calendy.herokuapp.com request_id=510f9bf5-29de-4ad6-b02d-4c937edbe1a1 fwd="24.205.62.204" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=44ms status=304 bytes=93
```

—————

**UPDATE 2**:

Ok, so I kept playing with the code and discovered three things:

1. The code works with posts created AFTER the method is implemented, ie: none of the `post.copy` from posts created before the push to Heroku are displayed, no matter what's inside of `post.copy`
2. Once we implement the method, `post.copy` is displayed ONLY IF it contains one of the elements that we are looking for with the regex, ie: `http`, `#` and `@`. Does that make any sense?
3. All the above actually also happens locally, unlike what I observed initially.

—————

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: So, nothing at all shows up when you run it through the highlight function? Try NOT running it through the function, does anything show up then?

Comment: Yes, when I remove the highlight function, it works just fine: the string is displayed correctly. Any idea how to test for this?

Comment: The debug shows nothing really, it's hard to say. Just ensure `post.copy` DOES have content; try with/without `raw`; try with a different string. Anything?

Comment: Thanks for checking out. I updated the question, as you can see in the **UPDATE 2** section.

Comment: I found a solution, you can check it out below if you are interested. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the problem.

I launched IRB in Terminal an ran a few tests:

```
h = "hello"
h.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
# => nil

l = "http://www.link.com"
l.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
# => "<span class=\"highlight\">http://www.link.com</span>"
```

The problem actually happens when the string I am trying to highlight **DOES NOT** contain any of the patterns we are looking for with the regex.

To fix the issue, I had to replace `.gsub!` with `.gsub`, and implement conditional statements, so that the method returns the initial string unchanged when no pattern was detected, instead of nil.

This is my new `posts_helper.rb`:

```
module PostsHelper

  def link_highlight(string)
    init1 = string
    result1 = string.to_s.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
    if result1.nil?
      init1
    else
      result1
    end
  end

  def hashtag_highlight(string)
    init2 = string
    result2 = string.to_s.gsub!(/\S*#(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/, '<span class="highlight">#\1</span>')
    if result2.nil?
      init2
    else
      result2
    end
  end

  def mention_highlight(string)
    init3 = string
    result3 = string.to_s.gsub(/\B(\@[a-z0-9_-]+)/i, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
    if result3.nil?
      init3
    else
      result3
    end
  end

  def new_highlight(string)
    link_highlight(string)
    hashtag_highlight(string)
    mention_highlight(string)
  end

end
```

This may not be the cleanest / leanest code, but it works — both locally and remotely — and it allows me to chain all three methods in the `new_highlight` final method.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub!` returns nil when no changes are made, so you have two approaches.

You can leave the helpers mostly as is, but change the last one to

```
def new_highlight(string)
  link_highlight(string)
  hashtag_highlight(string)
  mention_highlight(string)
  string
end
```

Personally I don't like this, because I wouldn't expect a view helper to modify its argument. It wouldn't be hard to accidentally wind up changing the data in the database like this.

Alternatively change the various methods to look like

```
def link_highlight(string)
  string.gsub(...)
end
```

And change the final helper to be

```
def new_highlight(string)
  mention_highlight(
    hashtag_highlight(
      link_highlight(string)
    )
  )
end
```

You can rewrite that last one in a number of ways if you feel like it, eg

```
%i(link_highlight hashtag_highlight mention_highlight).inject(string) do |value, transform|
  public_send(transform, value)
end
```

Although I don't think I would bother for a simple case like this (although it does make me wish for elixir's pipeline operator)